# Performing SSR and Client-side Interactions like Voting in the Same Page in Next.js 13.4.10

Tags: next.js13

I'm trying to build a feature in Next.js where an SSR-generated page has a voting button to update the votes of a post.

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
interface Post {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    vote: number;
}

async function vote(postId: number, vote: number) {
    // update post vote
}

async function getPosts(): Promise<Post[]> {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    const posts: Post[] = await res.json();
    return posts;
}

export default async function Home() {
    const posts = await getPosts();
    return (
        <>
            {posts.map((post: Post) => (
                <div key={post.id}>
                    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                    <p>{post.body}</p>
                    <p>vote: {post.vote}</p>
                    <button> + </button>{' '}<button> - </button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}
```

To run the vote() function, I need to use useEffect or 'use client' which makes the contents of the posts rendered on the client side, making the content invisible to search engines.

What I want to do are the following two things:

Deliver content via SSR
Perform operations such as voting on the client side.
Is it impossible to do these two things on a single page with Next.js?

I'm currently using Next.js version 13.4.10."

Answer (score 0):

By separating the VoteButton into a separate component, we were able to address the two requirements:

1. VoteButton operates interactively on the client-side.
2. Home performs server-side rendering for Posts.

With this approach, we have successfully achieved both of these objectives.

VoteButton.tsx:

```
'use client'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface Post {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    vote: number;
}

interface VoteButtonProps {
    post: Post;
    onVote: (postId: number, vote: number) => Promise<void>;
}

const VoteButton: React.FC<VoteButtonProps> = ({ post, onVote }) => {
    const [vote, setVote] = useState(post.vote);

    useEffect(() => {
        setVote(post.vote);
    }, [post]);

    const handleVote = async (increment: number) => {
        await onVote(post.id, increment);
        setVote(v => v + increment);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <p>vote: {vote}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleVote(1)}> + </button>{' '}
            <button onClick={() => handleVote(-1)}> - </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default VoteButton;
```

Home.tsx:

```
import VoteButton from './VoteButton';

interface Post {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    vote: number;
}

async function vote(postId: number, vote: number) {
    // update post vote
}

async function getPosts(): Promise<Post[]> {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    const posts: Post[] = await res.json();
    return posts;
}

export default async function Home() {
    const posts = await getPosts();
    return (
        <>
            {posts.map((post: Post) => (
                <div key={post.id}>
                    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                    <p>{post.body}</p>
                    <VoteButton post={post} onVote={vote} />
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}
```